# I want my Dialogflow bot to say a message which includes the result from a MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, dialogflow-es

I am querying a collection in MongoDB from Dialoglow Fulfillment. I then want my bot to respond with a message which includes this query. The code in the function of the Dialogflow Fulfillment is:

```
function readRecord(agent){
var name;
MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, client) {
   const collection = client.db("test").collection("data");
    collection.find({fname: 'Example'}).toArray(function(err, result){
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        name = result.lname;
        agent.add("Found last name: ", name);
    });
    client.close();
});
```

}

When I run this I get no response from my from the bot. When I `console.log(result)` the information is there but I can't seem to get the bot to say it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the intent handler expects you to return a Promise if you are doing any asynchronous functions - like accessing a database. The easiest way to do this is to change from using callbacks with MongoDB to using versions of the functions that return Promises, and then to return the promise.

I haven't tested, but something like this might work

```
return MongoClient.connect( uri )
  .then( client => {
    const collection = client.db("test").collection("data");
    return collection.find({fname: 'Example'}).toArray();
  })
  .then( result => {
    let name = result[0].lname;
    agent.add("Found last name: "+name);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks that worked for me. The one change I made let name = result[0].lname instead of let name = result.lname

Comment: Thanks. I had based the code on your original, and I've now updated it.